# Keep button in same position when rotate device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Im trying to create the same effect as the native camera app.

Would like to keep the a button at the same exact position upon rotating the device and support all device orientations.

The button should only rotate[image]

Answer (score 0):

all need to be done is to lock device orientation like so:

```
 UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

and:

```
  override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
```

one this done - use CoreMotion to detect phone orientation :
1. set up device motion detection:

```
func startDeviceMotion() {
        if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
            self.motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 10.0 / 60.0
            self.motion.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true
            self.motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xMagneticNorthZVertical)

            self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: (10.0/60.0), repeats: 
            true,block: { (timer) in
                self.deviceRotated()
            })
            RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        }
}
```

2. Handle rotation:

   ```
   func deviceRotated() {                                                    
       if let deviceMotion = motion.deviceMotion {
       let degree = deviceMotion.attitude.roll * 180 / .pi
       print(degree)
       switch degree {
       case -40 ... 40:
           UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation = .portrait
           break
       case 50 ... 130:
           UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation = .landscapeLeft
           break
       case -130 ... -50:
           UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation = .landscapeRight
           break
       default:
           break
       }
   } }
   ```

Note: On each orientation i changed the device status bar orientation, but keep device locked on portrait. 
Since I used code motion to detect device rotation changes - even if end user will lock the device rotation, this solution will work perfectly fine.